# Creating an aggregate RSS feed from RSS-less search results

Tags: rss, yahoo-pipes

So, say I'm a journalist, who wants some way of easily posting links to stories I've written that are published to my newspaper's website. Alas, my newspaper's website doesn't offer user-level RSS feeds (user-level anything for journalists, really).

Running a search (I.e., http://www.calgaryherald.com/search/search.html?q=Rininsland) brings up everything I've done in reverse chronological order (albeit with some duplicates; ignore for now, will deal with later). **Is there any way I can parse this into an RSS feed?**

It seems like Yahoo! Pipes might be an easy way to do this, but I'm open to whatever.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this would be a great use of Yahoo Pipes, but it appears that the search page you cited has a [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt) file, which Pipes respects. This means that Pipes will not pull data from the page.

For more info: "How do I keep Pipes from accessing my web pages?"
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=troubleshooting#q14

You would have to write a scraper yourself that makes an HTTP request to that URL, parses the response, and writes RSS as output. This could be done in many server-side environments such as PHP, Python, etc.

---

EDIT: Feedity provides a service to scrape web pages into feeds. Here is a Feedity feed of your search url:
http://feedity.com/rss.aspx/calgaryherald-com/UFJWUVZQ

However, unless you sign up for a subscription ($3.25/mo), this feed will be subject to the following constraints:

> Free feeds created
>   without an account are limited to 5
>   items and 10 hours update interval.
>   Free feeds created without an account
>   are automatically purged from our
>   system after 30 days of inactivity.

Comment: Hmm. It appears the correct answer is "Upgrade your CMS to produce user-level feeds." Thanks!

Comment: Or, rather than feedity, use open.dapper.net, which is free (for now)

Answer (score 0):

Provided it's just links and a timestamp you want for each article then the Yahoo  Pipes **Search module** will return the latest 10 in it's search index of the Herlad site.